# G2O BlockSolver Initialization Crash on Unix System

Tags: ros, ros2, linux, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a project which possesses and uses G2O library, it runs on both platforms(win/Unix).

***(WINDOW PASSED / UNIX CRASHED)***

We can see in both platforms, these lines:

```
g2o::SparseOptimizer optimizer;
g2o::BlockSolver_6_3::LinearSolverType * linearSolver;

linearSolver = new g2o::LinearSolverDense<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3::PoseMatrixType>();
```

Next steps, in window os we have this:

```
g2o::BlockSolver_6_3 * solver_ptr = new g2o::BlockSolver_6_3(linearSolver);
g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg* solver = new g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg(solver_ptr);
```

But Unix system can't compile those lines because it says

> ***my_file_G2o.cpp:*** *In member function 'int *Refiner_G2O::refinePose(cv::Mat&, const std::vector<cv::Point3_ >&, const std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&, const cv::Mat&, float, std::vector&)':* **my_file_G2o.cpp** **--> no matching function for call to** *'g2o::BlockSolver<g2o::BlockSolverTraits<6, 3>::BlockSolver(g2o::BlockSolver<g2o::BlockSolverTraits<6, 3>::LinearSolverType*&)'*
> ^
> In file included from *G2o/include/g2o/core/block_solver.h:199:0*,
> G2o/include/g2o/core/***block_solver.hpp:40:1***: **note: candidate:** g2o::BlockSolver::BlockSolver(std::unique_ptr) [with Traits = g2o::BlockSolverTraits<6, 3>; typename Traits::LinearSolverType = g2o::LinearSolver<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0> >]
> BlockSolver::BlockSolver(std::unique_ptr linearSolver)

When I see these errors, I complete my Unix code with this new block

```
auto solver_ptr = g2o::make_unique<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3>(linearSolver); // [SEGFAULT LINE]
auto solver = g2o::make_unique<g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg>(solver_ptr);
optimizer.setAlgorithm(solver.get());
```

So now, I can build/run but I meet a segfault on the line with **[SEGFAULT LINE]** tag.

I don't understand, why? if someone has an idea I want to understand how in Window it works and not in Unix system, will feel wonderful if you help.

LINUX Version: Ubuntu 16.04
CMAKE Version: 3.11.4

Best regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299424/g2o-blocksolver-initialization-crash-on-unix-system/) by [Simontraww](https://answers.ros.org/users/36792/simontraww/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED:

G2O optimise:

```
g2o::SparseOptimizer optimizer;

auto linearSolver = std::make_unique<g2o::LinearSolverDense<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3::PoseMatrixType>>();

auto solver = new g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg(std::make_unique<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3>(std::move(linearSolver)));

optimizer.setAlgorithm(solver);
```

MISC.H:

```
template<typename T, typename ...ArgTs>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(ArgTs&& ...args)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<ArgTs>(args)...));
};
```

---

Originally posted by [Simontraww](https://answers.ros.org/users/36792/simontraww/) with karma: 16 on 2018-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vignesh_93](https://answers.ros.org/users/65377/vignesh_93/) on 2020-12-12**:
Can you explain the MISC.H, do we need to create this file separately or we can add this to the existing file itself ?